# cfhttp over secure connections

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am having an issue using cfhttp to connect to a web service over a secure connection. I installed the certificate to the servers keystore awhile back and everything has been working fine. This morning it has stopped working. The certificate still has a year to go so it is not expired. I have not made any changes to the server. I've checked the cacerts file to ensure the certerficate is still in the store and it is there. Anybody have any idea what could have happened to cause this?

I found the problem. The service I was calling recently changed their internal ip addresses. This altered the cert which looked like the same cert to me but was actually different. Saved and installed the cert and we are back in business.

Comment: Are you able to make any http request without ColdFusion?  Maybe try wget or through the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can make a non secure http request through ColdFusion, and I can call the service through a browser.

Comment: Could there be a firewall blocking your SSL traffic?

Comment: The network admins have told me they have not made any changes and this worked before 3:45 this morning.

Comment: Do you get any errors or response when switching to SSL?  Have you checked your application.log file?

Comment: Yeah, checked the log file, nothing in there that relates to this. I get a Connection Failure in the Filecontent response and the Response Header is an empty struct.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons that could result in your problem.  Unfortunately, wihtout any more specfifics about what is happening (error message, dump, etc) other than just "stopped working" we can't really help you.  Please provide a dump of the CFTTP scope, including the status code and message.  If it is a certificate issue, I would expect to see a "peer not authenticated" response message.  Otherwise, it could be a problem with the routing (firewall) or the destinatoin server may have initiated HTTP compression which requires an additional work-around to access via CFTTP.

We will be able to narrow it down after seeing what the error is.

Comment: Here is a dump of the cfhttp response.                                     struct
Charset  [empty string]
ErrorDetail  I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
Filecontent  Connection Failure
Header  [empty string]
Mimetype  Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader 
struct [empty]
Statuscode  Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
Text  YES

Answer (score 0):

First thing I always do in cases like this is log into the desktop of the server and check resolution, hops, ip addresses etc myself.

For example, if the server on the other end has a new IP address they will update DNS - but CF may not get that new IP until time has elapsed or the instance is restarted. It has a very long time to live (can be adjusted but by default it is lengthy).

Or, your internal DNS server may be failing you. Or if the server is local (inside the same network) but DNS is not set up correctly then you might get the "outside" address when you need the "inside" address.

HTTP compressions (mentioned by user1431209) is a good thing to check as well - and check  intermediate certificates too.  That's all I got :)